# how to call actions from pinia store?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

How I can call action from pinia store in vue 3 component?
I use composition API.
For example, I would like to import 'openLessonCard' - it is action in pinia store.
But this method for import don't work..

```
<script setup>
import { openLessonCard } from '../../stores/lessonsN.js';
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'


defineProps({
  data: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
  nocollapse: {
  type: Boolean,
  },
});

const reviewLevel = computed(() => {
  return Object.values(this.data.criteria).filter((i) => i === true).length;
})

async function editReviews(id, text, a, b, c, d, e) {
  let review = await this.$api.call("reviews.edit", {
    id,
    text,
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
  });
  this.$Message("ok");
}
```

Comment: Action is called from the store instance. So you need to get the store instance first. Please follow [this guilde](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html#usage-with-setup). If you still can not figure out what is the problem, please show the `lessonsN.js`'s code

Comment: in the example you attached above you are not using the action at all, where and how do you want to use it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a store instance and call actions

```
 const store = useLessonsNStore()

 store.openLessonCard()
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember, "Actions are the equivalent of methods in components" (Pinia documentation).

You are using `<script setup>` in your example code.

Then, in your component...

1. Import your store normally:

```
import { useLessonsNStore } from '../../stores/lessonsN';
```

2. Get an instance of your store:

```
const lessonsN = useLessonsNStore();
```

3. Invoke the action like a method

```
lessonsN.openLessonCard();
```

More info: [enter link description here](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html)